# Is the EBS volume mounted ? and where?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, filesystems, volume, mount-point

In my `EC2 instance`, that is attached to a volume `EBS` of `100GB`, I run this command:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ lsblk

NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  100G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0    8G  0 part /
```

Here is the file `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=ue9a1ccd-a7dd-77f8-8be8-08573456abctkv       /   ext4    defaults       1       1
```

I want to understand: why only the volume of 8GB has a mount point ?
Also, is the fact of mounting a volume on root '/', means that all the content of root is being stored on EBS volume?

Comment: In your EC2 instance, there are 2 volumes attached. xvda1 is your root volume. For additional volumes, you need to attach it manually (or use user data to automate). Documentation can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html

Comment: No, only one volume is attached. @KrishnaKumarR

Comment: @Somar BOTH volumes are attached (because you see them in `lsblk`)  but only xvda1 mounted. As  Krishna Kumar said, it should be mounted - either manually or using 'user data'

Comment: @Putnik I'm confused. This instance only has one volume attached. Not TWO volumes. where does the volume of 8Go come from?

Comment: This is what I have 
`Root device:
/dev/xvda
---
Block devices:
/dev/xvda`

Comment: At your quote both me and Krishna Kumar see two volumes: 1) xvdf  100G  unmounted and 2) xvda 8G with its partition xvda1 mounted to '/'. Could you please be more clear in the question? Are you sure you aren't confused with 'attached vs mounted' and/or 'drive/volume vs partition'?

Comment: @Putnik I'm so sorry!!! I edited the quote. I was showing the wrong mapping. Please forgive.

Comment: Then the second volume is not attached. Make sure you've attached it to the same instance you're ssh-ing  in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to understand: why only the volume of 8GB has a mount point ?

Because additional volumes are not formatted/mounted by default. AWS does not know whether you'd like to have ext4 or NTFS or something else as well as which mount point you'd like to have.

> Also, is the fact of mounting a volume on root '/', means that all the content of root is being stored on EBS volume?

Yes if you have EBS-backed instance (unlike so-called instance-backed instances) and if you do not have other volumes **mounted** (not to be confused with 'attached')

p.s. as far as I see, you initially had created 8GB volume then resized it via AWS console to 100GB. Pls note you resized the EBS volume (`xvda`) but did not resize the partition (`xvda1`). AWS will not resize it automatically by the same reason: it doesn't know how you're going to use the extra space.